# How to add Delete Button of each row of to Jquery DataTable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I am using Jquery DataTable, I want to use Edit and Delete Functionality for each row of DataTable and I have completed Edit Part on click of DataTable Row. Now i am looking for delete functionality but I am not able to achieve same.

I tried like this:

**DataTable Binding Code:**

```
        function LoadTableData() {
        var params = {
            UserName: $('#txtUserName').val(), UserID: $('#txtUserID').val(),
            Status: $('input[name="Status"]:checked').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: 'UserService.asmx/Get_Data_MobileUser',
            method: 'post',
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (data) {
                $('#example').dataTable({
                    destroy: true,
                    data: data /*JSON.parse(data)*/,
                    columns: [
                        {
                            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                                return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
                            }
                        },

                        { 'data': 'Status', class: 'editable text' },
                        { 'data': 'USER_LOGIN', class: 'editable text' },
                        { 'data': 'USER_NAME', class: 'editable text' },

                    ],

                    "columnDefs": [
                        {
                           
                            "render": function (data, type, row) {      
                                return '<button type="button">Delete</button>';
                                //return data + ' (' + row[3] + ')';
                            },
                            "targets": 0
                        },
                        { "visible": false, "targets": [3] }
                    ],
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    select: true,

                    buttons: [
                        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                    ],
                    "searching": true,
                    "paging": true,
                    "info": true,
                    "language": {
                        "emptyTable": "No data available"
                    },
                    "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
                        $("td:first", nRow).html(iDisplayIndex + 1);
                        return nRow;
                    },
                })
                //function createButton(buttonType, rowID) {
                //    var buttonText = buttonType == "edit" ? "Edit" : "Delete";
                //    //return '<button class="' + buttonType + '" type="button">' + buttonText + '</button>';
                //    return "<a href='#my_modal' data-toggle='modal' class='open-AddBookDialog' data-book-id='my_id_value'><img src='Images/delete.png' height='20' width='20'></a>"
                //}
            },
            error: function (err) { // Added this event to capture the failed requests.
                console.log(err.responseText);
            }
        });
    };
```

**Table Structure**

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width: 100%">
      <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>S.No</th>
           <th>Status</th>
           <th>User Login</th>
           <th>User Name</th>
           <th>Delete</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
</table>
```

But on console window I am getting Error :

> Uncaught TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.Editor is not a constructor

Am I missing any CDN for that?

[image]

What I am going wrong?

Comment: Editor is an extension of DataTables that is not free. Is that what you expected to be using? You can put buttons in rows easily using a render callback of standard dataTables also

Comment: you're not using DataTables the way I use it, but I can offer a hint.
in my case, I use server-side code, so my delete function calls the server to remove the row, then I use .draw() on the DataTable to rebuild the view.
in your case, you will need to do the same - adjust the JSON data, and rebuild the view.

Comment: @KaeVerens if i use server side code then my form will be post back ryt ? that I am not looking.

Comment: @charlietfl I am new in Jquery DataTable could you please add Code in Answer

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html

Comment: @charlietfl as per mention Link I am not able to see Delete functionality. could you please explain me in details Please ? I removed Editor logic I have added `"columnDefs" :[{"render: function(data, type, row{return data + ' (' + row[3] + ')';})"}]` but no changes

Comment: You need a `target` index for which column also. Then you can return an html button instead

Comment: @charlietfl i have added new  `"columnDefs"` kindly check my updated code and please suggest me where now i Am going wrong?

Comment: @charlietfl i have used target index as `"targets": 0`  and returning `return '<button type="button">Delete</button>';` but i am not able see button on my page

Comment: Hard to help without a live demo in a sandbox site like jsfiddle, codesandbox, codepen, jsbin etc

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry to say but i don't know how to add `jsfiddle` on stack overflow

Comment: Just a  link is fine

Comment: @charlietfl i am working on local machine can we create room and there we can discuss Please ?